# pi's password is lost in every reboot

Tags: raspbian, login, password

I am newbee at Pi3B.
I installed Jessie at Pi3B board.

Whenever I reboot the board, the pi's password was changed into unknown value.
So, I delete pi's password encryption field from /etc/password everytime and reset the password.
Then the password remains until I reboot. This is stupid.
Can anyone tell me what is wrong on the password ?

P.S. I found similar questions in this forum. But, no answers found yet.
I am not using WiFi and my ssh and internet work well after I reset the password.

To change the password for pi, I simply used $passwd command. It seems work well. About the password, user-entered passwod is eventually encrypted and wrote onto the /etc/password file. I tried raspi-config to change pi's password, but, still the same problem.

Comment: have you changed it in terminal using **passwd** ?

Comment: yes. After the change, it remains until I reboot the system.

Comment: Oh, after reboot, I directly remove the password field of /etc/password file and then ran passwd command.

Comment: **HOW** are you attempting to change the password? List the **EXACT** command entered. Is there any reason you are not using `raspi-config` to change the password? **NOTE** the password is **NOT** stored in `/etc/password`

Comment: @Totoro **DO NOT** add detail in comments, edit your question. You need to explain what you mean by "delete pi's password from /etc/password"

Comment: OK. I updated my question....

Comment: @Milliways: The password is not stored anywhere, of course, but it is possible to delete a field in `/etc/passwd` and make the account passwordless.  Also, a hash of the password (== a *one-way* encrytion) will appear in that field after you set one, until `pwconv` is run, at which point it will be replaced with an `x`.

Comment: In any case @Totoro this is a non-reproducible problem, meaning anyone else who does the same thing will not have the same result.  Either the pi is magically cursed, or you have made a mistake or left out some crucial piece of information.  You should try a very simple password (`abc123`) to make sure there is no mistake, and perhaps run `sudo pwconv` after you set it to make sure there are no hijinx going on there.

Comment: The encrypted password is stored in `/etc/shadow` not in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: How do you reboot the PI? Which command do you use?

Comment: I can come up with two causes - you left it with the default password on the open net and someone cracked it, or the keyboard's locale is somehow messing up how it interprets the password. Or in the case of the a corrupted `passwd`/`shadow` file - or to actually change the password - you should edit *`/etc/shadow`* **using `passwd`** (and note the above comments). If you have edited the files directly (can work well as a off-line hack for a forgotten Pi password!), you can check the files using `pwck -r /etc/passwd` &  `pwck -r /etc/shadow`

Comment: I’ve seen a similar issue where the SD card was on the way out BUT the password did not change from the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

[This is a workaround]

I'm not sure why, but the "pi" SSH password seems to be invalidated upon reboot. Eventually I gave up trying to figure out why and how and worked around this by creating my own user. With this user I can logon after reboot.

Not using the default "pi" user for SSH login may seem to be not too bad from a security perspective anyway.

Hope this helps.

PS: I added my user to the groups "sudo" to install software and "audio" to get the Pi to play sound.